# Applying css to the table row dynamically created with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vue.js

So I have table, where rows are created dynamically using v-for:

```
<table>
  <tr><th class='name'>Name</th><th>Surname</th></tr>
  <tr v-for='data in datas'><td class='name'>@{{data.name}}</td><td>@{{data.surname}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

And then, using jQuery, I want to hide the column with class 'name', but when I make

```
$('.name').hide();
```

Only header disappears. I suppose it's because the row is made dynamically, but how could I handle this?

I've tried:

1. making each() function on all elements with this class,
2. writing script like `.css('display','none')`, not `hide()`

but it didn't help. Strange, but `alert()` in `each()` fires each time it should, but `hide()` ignores added elements

More concrete data:
the table itself:

```
<table class="striped bordered responsive">
     <thead>
         <tr><th class="stat-table-creatives" colspan="2">Creative info</th><th>Impressions</th><th>Clicks</th><th>CTR</th><th>CPC</th><th>Price per unit</th><th>Sum</th><th class="stat-table-date">Date</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr v-for="stat in stats"><td class="stat-table-creatives">@{{ stat.creativeTitle }}</td><td class="stat-table-creatives">@{{ stat.creativeType }}</td><td>@{{ stat.impressions }}</td><td>@{{ stat.clicks }}</td><td>@{{ stat.ctr }}</td><td>@{{ stat.cpc }}</td><td>@{{ stat.client_price }}</td><td>@{{ stat.sum }}</td><td class="stat-table-date">@{{ stat.date }}</td></tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

function called on button click

```
getJsonForStats: function(filters){
    if((filters[0]=='creative')||(filters[1]=='creative')){
        $('.stat-table-creatives').show();
    } else {
        $('.stat-table-creatives').hide();
    }
    if((filters[0]=='date')||(filters[1]=='date')){
        $('.stat-table-date').show();
    } else {
        $('.stat-table-date').hide();
    }
});
```

The function is called from another function, which is called on v-on:click

Comment: Why don't you add a CSS definition like so `.name { display: none; }`

Comment: @aifrim I need this column to be shown when document loads, and to hide it on button click

Comment: Ok then this `$("#hide-button").click(function() {
  $(".name").hide();
});` applied at `domready` should work :)

Comment: Have you tried `$("#TableID .name").hide();`

Comment: @aifrim but it doesn't

Comment: @Matt.k yup. doesn't work as well

Comment: Provide the data to use :)

Comment: you should provide your component definition. The important part here, is where are you calling the `.hide()` method, and the selectors you are using. Maybe provide jsfiddle too

Comment: @aifrim added in edit

Comment: I think Vue.js does not allow jquery select the element . to make sure,you can add one static row above it then it will select your class name .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/114/   as an example for dynamic elements

Comment: @Matt.k yeah, looks like header is accessible because it's static. I will probably have to find another way, maybe without vue

Comment: Well it can be solved without jQuery, v-if and v-show can be used instead

Answer (score 0):

jQuery works just fine with Vue dynamically created table. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/9o69f2yr/

I believe the problem will be on how your application is loading, your filters, etc.

Depending on how you are trying to access the table rows, you may want to make sure that DOM is completely updated before querying it. You can use Vue's nextTick (http://vuejs.org/api/#Vue-nextTick).
Inside your Vue method, before you try to hide the rows, in your example, calling `getJsonForStats` method, you can do

```
this.$nextTick(function() {
   //DOM updated and ready to rock and roll
   this.getJsonForStats(..your filter params...);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

suppose it's because you use the same class for `<th>` and `<td>`

try `<th class="name-th">` and then `$(".name-th").hide();` `$(".name").hide();`
maybe it will help

**UPD**:

I don't know.. this code is working perfectly:

```
<table id="tab" border='1'>
                <tr><th class='name'>Name</th><th>Surname</th></tr>
                <tr><td class='name'>n</td><td>s</td></tr>
</table>
<input id="click" type="button" value="Hide" />
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click").click(function(){
        $("#tab").find(".name").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: It's the same like if I used 'th.name' and 'td.name' selectors, which I've also tried and didn't succeed